# VSTS REST API: 401 Unauthorized on work items API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I receive a `401 Unauthorized` when trying to query VSTS' [work item API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items). For example:

```
https://{account}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/8622
```

On the other hand, I can query other endpoints just fine, for example:

```
https://{account}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects
```

I am using [Basic Authentication](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/auth/overview) and according to the docs this should not be a problem. I also allowed all scopes on the token.

Comment: What's the result if you change the Basic auth from PAT to **Alternate authentication credentials** instead?

Comment: Does it occur if you create a new PAT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you've included `vso.work` or `vso.work_write` in the scopes section of your manifest.

See scopes section of [the manifest reference](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/manifest#scopes).

Answer (score 0):

when you create a PAT manually, make sure you enable the scopes required for that PAT

you cant query work items because the scope *Read* is not enabled
for work items

at the time of PAT creation